# create login with Spring security Core 3.0.0M1

Tags: grails, spring-security

i am trying to upgrade my application from `grails 2.1.1` to `grails 3.0.5`.

i tried to install `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'` 
and create User, Role and RequestMap with `s2-quickstart` .

as i know in grails 2.1.1, i after install spring security plugin, at i have `loginController.groovy` and `logoutController.groovy` and i user `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.groovy` to create  a login.

but after i in `grails 3.0.5`, i cannot find `loginController.groovy` and `logoutController.groovy`

i am confuse with this version..

what must i do now to create a login page with database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those controllers and the login controller's GSPs are in the plugin now - this was changed in the 2.0 plugin and is the same in the 3.0 plugin. You don't have to do anything if the plugin's controllers and GSPs are sufficient.

If you want to customize how they work, just copy the plugin's file(s) to your application in the same relative location and edit those. Grails always lets you override files like this since the app code is compiled after the plugin code.

For Grails 3 this is a bit different because plugins are always compiled into jar files, so you can get the source [from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/).

Comment: In Grails 3 I have spring security working and I can `/login`.  `/logout` gives me a `404` I have set `postOnly: false` in `application.yml`  Where is `/logout`?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I copied these controllers from one of my other application of the Grails 2 version. Few classes and implementation is changed, but it's more or less same.

Comment: yes..grails 3+ is  more confuse X_X...i can access localhost:8080/login/auth but after i create domain...that link become an error page...when i hit localhost:8080 it will redirect to /login/auth..i still confuse with this..